# Return empty result in requery QueryRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, orm, kotlin

I'm using `QueryRecyclerAdapter` to display database request result in `RecyclerView`. I have to implement `performQuery()` method with `Result<MyDTO>` return type. 
When, with previous condition, I know, that there are `null` response, but I am not want to produce exception, I must return empty `Result`. But I can't explicitly create it via constructor - it's not `public`. So, for now I return select query with incorrect id, which is not seems to be good solution. 
Is there are another way to **return empty result** in Requery?

Comment: You should provide some code so we can actually help

Comment: Ok, here is `performQuery` code: https://pastebin.com/rFUVFBir

Comment: If we are trying to find current feat's children, we first need to determine is such object exists in database. If it's true, we can collect all object, which prerequisites field contains our feat's name, and return empty list otherwise. If we are trying to get parent feats, we must first get prerequisite list, separated by comma (I'm not creator of this database, so can't change it to one-to-many relation with ids) and, if it is not empty, query elements for each name

Comment: Can you intercept and return a MatrixCursor

Comment: No, I have to return Result<Feat> object, which is not subtype of MatrixCursor. https://github.com/requery/requery/blob/master/requery/src/main/java/io/requery/query/Result.java